# why javascript map parsint of ['10','10','10'] gives nonsense?

Tags: javascript

> xs = ['10','10','10']
>   [ '10', '10', '10' ]
>
> xs.map(parseInt)
>   [ 10, NaN, 2 ]
>   xs.map(parseFloat)
>   [ 10, 10, 10 ]

why is the result 10,nan,2 for first one?
why the second one is right?

Comment: use Math.floor to [].map() numbers into Integers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.map()` passes multiple arguments to its callback as in callback(element, index, array).

`parseInt()` uses that 2nd argument `index` that `.map()` passes as the radix distorting its result.

`parseFloat()`, on the other hand, only expects one argument so it works as expected.

---

If you pass instead a callback function, you can avoid that issue because then you control how `parseInt()` is called:

```
xs.map(item => parseInt(item, 10));
```